# Laravel - Setting up common storage for staging and production post deployment

Tags: laravel, storage, shared, production, staging

I have taken over a Laravel project that has been deployed for a while now that has been using separate storage folders for files that are uploaded to the respective websites. My experience with Laravel is limited. I want to use a single location to store files for both Staging and Production Laravel websites now to reduce storage space being taken up by duplicate files.

I have managed to set up Staging to save its files into the Productions storage folder. The issue I have now is that the `<input>` component we use to upload files, is trying to source those files for preview from Stagings storage folder instead of Productions.

What can I do to make the `<input>` component source the file for previewing, from the correct location (being Productions storage) instead of Stagings storage folder?

I investigating symlinking with the intent of linking Stagings storage folder to Productions public folder and gave up on that since it only allows one folder to link at a time.

As mentioned earlier I have successively set up the upload path to use the Productions storage folder in `config/filesystems.php` but I have not been able to find a method of setting the source of the `<input>` component so it will use the correct URL to preview the file that has been assigned to it.

Updated storage path reference

**filesystems.php**

```
'public' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('../../mywebsite.com/storage/app/public'),
    'url' => 'https://mywebsite.com/storage',
    'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

How the image path is created

**FileUploadController.php**

```
$filePath = Storage::url($request->file($file)->storeAs('/', Carbon::now()->timestamp . $request->file($file)->hashName(), 'public'));
```

I'm not sure what other code could be useful here, feel free to ask and I'll do my best to supply it.

I was expecting that the `<input>` component would be receiving the file URL based on where the file is stored to display for the preview. But it appears as though the file path starts from `/storage/my-file-here.jpeg` and is concatenated with the Staging websites URL before populating the source for the `<input>` component.

Comment: but I have not been able to find a method of setting the source of the component so it will use the correct storage location. can you elaborate on this part?

Comment: After re-reading that part I realise it was worded poorly, I have updated that section with the following: _but I have not been able to find a method of setting the source of the `<input>` component so it will use the correct URL to preview the file that has been assigned to it._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I went about solving this problem all wrong. I didn't need to change any code within the files.

The solution was setting up a symlink from the staging sites storage/app/public folder to point to production sites storage/app/public folder.